# Table adapter Update Fail

Tags: c#, .net, sql-update, tableadapter

I am using a table adapter method to update data on database ,I am updating two columns but one column fail to update other column updates correctly..what is the cause of this? how can i fix this issue? Please Help..

Here is the SP

```
USE [PNSBL7Data]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[EmpOTApr_Update]    Script Date: 6/28/2013 9:25:54 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmpOTApr_Update] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@AtnDetKy bigint,
@AprOT bigint,
@isAprOTMin bit

AS
--declare  @AprOt bigint
--declare @AtnDetExtKy bigint

--set @AtnDetExtKy = 112
--set @AprOt = 25
--SET NOCOUNT OFF;

UPDATE    AtnDetExt SET isAprOTMin=@isAprOTMin ,AprOTMins = @AprOT

WHERE     (AtnDetKy = @AtnDetKy)

SELECT     EmpMas.EmpNo, EmpMas.EmpNm, AtnDet.AtnDt, AtnDet.EmpKy, AtnDet.InDtm, AtnDet.OutDtm, AtnDetExt.OT1Mint AS NorOT, AtnDetExt.OT2Mint AS DouOT, 
                  AtnDetExt.OT3Mint AS TriOT, AtnDetExt.AprOTMins, AtnDet.AtnDetKy
FROM         AtnDet INNER JOIN
                  AtnDetExt ON AtnDet.AtnDetKy = AtnDetExt.AtnDetKy INNER JOIN
                  EmpMas ON AtnDet.EmpKy = EmpMas.EmpKy
WHERE     (AtnDet.AtnDetKy = @AtnDetKy) AND (AtnDetExt.AprOTMins = @AprOT)
```

Here's the table adapter update

[image]

Comment: isAprOT column is updating but AprOT wont? please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the datatype in DB and this adapter. It should be map correctly. And one more thing is check the source version also.